# How to Hide CheckBox of Selected Row from GridView using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, checkbox

I have a `GridView` with `CheckBox` in first column and `Button` on SecondLast column. When user Clicks on `Button` the `CheckBox` of `current row` must be `Invisible` using `Javascript`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true"
    PageSize="100" AllowSorting="true" DataSourceID="sqlUsers" DataKeyNames="ttppcid"
    Width="100%" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" EmptyDataText="No Data Found"
    OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Visible="true">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" Height="30" class="mychk" rowid="<%# Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
//some more templates here
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="70px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="BtnSource" runat="server" Text="Source" rowid="<%# Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>"
                    class="showButton" OnClick='<%# "return SetRowValues("+Eval("ttppcid")+",this.id,"+Eval("Fair")+","+Eval("Good")+","+Eval("Mint")+","+Eval("Poor")+","+Eval("Fair")+")"%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function SetRowValues(id, controlid, fair, good, mint, nnew, poor, broken) {
    var rowid = $("#" + controlid).attr("rowid");
    var chkBoxID;
    var chkRowid;
    $('.mychk').css("display", "block");

    $('.mychk').each(function() {

        chkBoxID = this.id;
        alert(chkBoxID);
        chkRowid = $("#" + chkBoxID).attr("rowid");
        alert(chkBoxID + " ROW :" + chkRowid);


        if (chkRowid == rowid) {
            $("#" + chkBoxID).css("display", "none");
        }
        else {
            $("#" + chkBoxID).css("display", "block");

        }
    });
return false;
}
```

All works fine just here in `alert` i get empty. NOT able to get the ID of the `CheckBox` Control

**Also Tried With:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $(".showButton").on("click", function() {
            alert(".showButton clicked");
            $(this).closest("tr").find(":checkbox").hide();
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

**Rendered CheckBox:**

```
<td align="center" style="width: 30px; display: block;">
   <span class="mychk" rowid="1" style="display: block; height: 30px;"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl02_chkSelect" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl02$chkSelect"></span>
</td>
```

**Rendered Button in Grid:**

```
<td align="center" style="width: 70px; display: block;">
 <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl03$BtnSource" value="Source" onclick="return SetRowValues(6,this.id,222.0000,222.0000,222.0000,222.0000,222.0000);WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl03$BtnSource&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl03_BtnSource" class="showButton" rowid="1" style="">
</td>
```

Any Idea?

Help Appreciated!

Comment: After you run the application what is the final html? Can you paste the html output?

Comment: You can not achieve this with javascript if i understood you correctly. The asp-button will make a postback and the hidden checkbox will be visible again. If you don't want to make a postback, use html-button.

Comment: hi @Esa, their is not postback as my return statement returns 'false' always. all works fine as i need just not able to hide checkbox.

Comment: You are using OnClick-property which is server side, do you mean OnClientClick instead? Anyway if you don't want postback, don't use asp-button in the first place.

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE, please check this piece of code: chkBoxID = this.id; 
Is this the id of the checkbox passed to the js function?
Also if you have the 'rowId' why dont you use that?

Comment: Do you want to hide the checkbox on the same row as the clicked button? Is this what you asked? If not, please tell me what it was so I can answer. Because my answer already did this.

Comment: sorry to say @Esa, this wont work as i said. YES is want to hide the checkbox of current row on button click but it wont do as expected..! This must be done without any postback too..!

Comment: Undeleted my earlier answer, which will do what you asked. All that was needed was to prevent the postback, as I commented earlier, don't use asp-button if you don't want postback.

Comment: It you add Table runat server inside gridview the you will find current click row and that will hide that current row according to click try this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my Complete Solution:

```
function SetRowValues(id, controlid, fair, good, mint, nnew, poor, broken) {
var rowid = $("#" + controlid).attr("rowid");
var chkBoxID;
var chkRowid;
$('span.mychk').each(function() {
 chkBoxID = $(this).attr('id');
  chkRowid = $(this).attr('rowid');
  if (chkRowid == rowid) {
       $(this).hide();
       $(this).closest("td").css("border","none");
  }
  else {
       $(this).show();
       $(this).closest("td").css("border", "1px solid grey");
   }
});
return false;
}
```

Thanks to all..! :)

Comment: glad u found the solution, but as if var rowid = $("#" + controlid).attr("rowid"); with this it was not taking control's id in ur previous code.. now how it started working?

Comment: hey @SagarS.Dhanorkar, all the code is same the only change is the way i selected attribute for the .mychk checkbox was wrong. so, it wont worked. have you noticed that in previous post i have used 'this.id' which is wrong it must be $(this).attr('id'). But after selecting the attribute i get the row id too..and it worked...! :D

Answer (score 0):

First to do this without postback, change the asp-button to, input type=button or a html-button:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true"
    PageSize="100" AllowSorting="true" DataSourceID="sqlUsers" DataKeyNames="ttppcid"
    Width="100%" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" EmptyDataText="No Data Found"
    OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Visible="true">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" Height="30" class="mychk" rowid="<%# Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
//some more templates here
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="70px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input type="button" class="showButton" value="Source"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and then use a script like this to hide the checkbox. You don't need the id of the checkbox for this, simply find the parent row and hide the checkbox:

```
$(function() {
    $(".showButton").on("click", function() {
          $(this).closest("tr").find(":checkbox").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not? You wanted to hide the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

**Try with below:**

```
var result = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> tr td input[id*="chkSelect"][type=checkbox]:checked').map(function () {

    return $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(2).text();

    }).get().join();
```

Comment: hi @Sagar S.Dhanorkar, i have pasted this in SetRowValues() javascript method. but it wont work..! any thing i am doing wrong plz let me know..!

Comment: will you plz explain the code i have not understood the thing .get(), .map & join() these are new to me..! so..?