# How to Find a CheckBox inside a Class and Hide the CheckBox using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, show-hide

I have a `Grid view` in which their is a **CheckBox** in first column. Now, i want to Hide a `CheckBox` of selected Row.
I have tried with the following to Hide `CheckBox` but it wont work.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true"
    PageSize="100" AllowSorting="true" DataSourceID="sqlUsers" DataKeyNames="ttppcid"
    Width="100%" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" EmptyDataText="No Data Found"
    OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Visible="true">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" Height="30" class="mychk" rowid="<%# Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
//some more templates here
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="70px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="BtnSource" runat="server" Text="Source" rowid="<%# Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>"
                    class="showButton" OnClick='<%# "return SetRowValues("+Eval("ttppcid")+",this.id,"+Eval("Fair")+","+Eval("Good")+","+Eval("Mint")+","+Eval("Poor")+","+Eval("Fair")+")"%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Javascript:

```
function SetRowValues(id, controlid, fair, good, mint, nnew, poor, broken) {
    var rowid = $("#" + controlid).attr("rowid");
    var chkBoxID;
    var chkRowid;
    $('.mychk').css("display", "block");

    $('.mychk').each(function() {

        chkBoxID = this.id;
        alert(chkBoxID);
        chkRowid = $("#" + chkBoxID).attr("rowid");
        alert(chkBoxID + " ROW :" + chkRowid);


        if (chkRowid == rowid) {
            $("#" + chkBoxID).css("display", "none");
        }
        else {
            $("#" + chkBoxID).css("display", "block");

        }
    });
return false;
}
```

**AlsoTRied With:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $(".showButton").on("click", function() {
            alert(".showButton clicked");
            $(this).closest("tr").find(":checkbox").hide();
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

**Rendered Markup:**

Rendered CheckBox:

```
<td align="center" style="width: 30px; display: block;">
   <span class="mychk" rowid="1" style="display: block; height: 30px;"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl02_chkSelect" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl02$chkSelect"></span>
</td>

**Rendered Button in Grid:**
<td align="center" style="width: 70px; display: block;">
 <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl03$BtnSource" value="Source" onclick="return SetRowValues(6,this.id,222.0000,222.0000,222.0000,222.0000,222.0000);WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl03$BtnSource&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl03_BtnSource" class="showButton" rowid="1" style="">
</td>
```

**NOTE: I want to hide the CheckBox where 'rowid' of Button matches with the 'rowid' of a CheckBox.**

Comment: You have already asked this question and it has already been answered, please don't repost same question. Use the original question and tell why the solution there does not work for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458044/how-to-hide-checkbox-of-selected-row-from-gridview-using-javascript

Comment: But still it wont work..

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NpC5q/3/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Solution:

```
 function SetRowValues(id, controlid, fair, good, mint, nnew, poor, broken) {
    var rowid = $("#" + controlid).attr("rowid");
    var chkBoxID;
    var chkRowid;
    $('span.mychk').each(function() {
     chkBoxID = $(this).attr('id');
      chkRowid = $(this).attr('rowid');
      if (chkRowid == rowid) {
           $(this).hide();
           $(this).closest("td").css("border","none");
      }
      else {
           $(this).show();
           $(this).closest("td").css("border", "1px solid grey");
       }
    });
    return false;
}
```